# VBA - How to hide or delete Userform TextBox Cursor in an while its value is updating

Tags: vba

I have a userform with a textbox in it to inform users what is happening in my code in background. I added a `change` event on my textbox and set **AutoSize** property of my userform to **Enabled** and wrote a code to resize my textbox and userform according to the length of the textbox's text at each stage. The only remaining problem is that there is always a blinking cursor at the end of the textbox at each stage. How do I hide or delete this cursor while updating the textbox text? I know that there is a solution which suggests to put another textbox and put a `.setfocus` on it in `userform_initialize` subroutine but this can not solve my problem since my userform and textbox is continuously updating.

Comment: Why not use a Label? It has a autosize prop

Comment: @RedHare Thank you for your response, Because label doen't have ```Change``` event

Comment: But you could use a hidden textbox for the change event and display in a label